# Vaadin setExpandRatio doesn't work

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

This code works, center panel expands correctly:

```
HorizontalLayout header = new HorizontalLayout(new Label("HEADER"));
HorizontalLayout center = new HorizontalLayout(new Label("CENTER"));
HorizontalLayout footer = new HorizontalLayout(new Label("FOOTER"));        
VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout(header, center, footer);
verticalLayout.setExpandRatio(center, 1.0f);
verticalLayout.setSizeFull();
setContent(verticalLayout);
```

But this code doesn't work, center panel expands but left and right panels are not visible:

```
VerticalLayout left = new VerticalLayout(new Label("LEFT"));
VerticalLayout center = new VerticalLayout(new Label("CENTER"));
VerticalLayout right = new VerticalLayout(new Label("RIGHT"));
HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout(left, center, right);
horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(center, 1.0f);
horizontalLayout.setSizeFull();
setContent(horizontalLayout);
```

Any idea why and how to make it work?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `VerticalLayout` has 100% width per default.

Set undefined width:

```
left.setSizeUndefinded();
right.setSizeUndefined();
```

or

```
left.setWidth(null);
right.setWidth(null);
```